# AWS Oracle RDS DATA_PUMP_DIR clean up

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services

So I am trying to clean up the DATA_PUMP_DIR with the function

`EXEC UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('DATA_PUMP_DIR','<file name>');`

as is described in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html#Oracle.Procedural.Importing.DataPumpS3.Step6

But the problem is that `EXEC` command is not recognized. `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.`

I have tried writing `execute` instead or writing `begin ... end` function but still this wouldn't work. Could there be some permission issues? If so how can I grant them to myself?

I am using oracle se2 12.1.

Edit:
I have tried running:

```
BEGIN 
        UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('DATA_PUMP_DIR','<file name>');
END;
```

which gives an error of

```
[Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: line 2, column 58:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( % ;
```

I have tried using declare before but it gives the same error:

```
DECLARE
        v_test tpch.region.R_NAME%type;
BEGIN 
        UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('DATA_PUMP_DIR','<file name>');
END;
```

I have also seen somewhere that you should put backslash before each ; sign like this:

```
BEGIN 
        UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('DATA_PUMP_DIR','<file name>')\;
END\;
```

This didn't work either.

Comment: EXEC or EXECUTE can only be used in some clients like sqlplus or sqldeveloper. 
Please provide the full PL/SQL block you tried (from BEGIN to END) and also the full error stack.

Comment: Done. I am using dbvisualizer too if that info tells you anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just installed sqlplus and ran the command from there